# How to resize image to match mnist images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I am a newbie, and have taken interest in learning about Tensorflow. Recently I came across the mnist digits dataset, and wanted to create my own Neural Network model, that would predict digits that i could draw on a simple pygame gui.

However, the mnist dataset seems to contain images of size 20x20 pixels, centered into a 28x28 grid. “Un-preprocessed” images fail to give the expected results.

My question is **how can I center and supposedly resize the image I draw to match the mnist images**?
[image: 1]
**This image of ‘5’, which is alot like the mnist images gets predicted as expected, i.e, a 5.**

---

[image: 2]
**However, this one does not get predicted correctly.**

---

Here’s full working code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pygame

# dataset of handwritten digits
# comes in as ((train_x,train_y),(test_x,test_y))
mnist = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
train_data, test_data = mnist
train_images, train_labels = train_data
test_images, test_labels = test_data
IMAGE_DIM = 28
IMAGE_SHAPE = (IMAGE_DIM, IMAGE_DIM)
TOTAL_PIXELS = IMAGE_DIM ** 2
TOTAL_CLASSES = 10

# view images on matplotlib
def view_images(images, labels):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    for i in range(25):
        plt.subplot(5, 5, i + 1)
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        plt.grid(False)
        plt.imshow(images[i])
        plt.xlabel(labels[i])
    plt.show()


# view_images(train_images,train_labels)

# each image is 28 x 28, 2d array
# each pixel in the 28 x 28 is a gray scale value, from 0-255
# scale this down to a range of 0-1
train_images = train_images / 255
test_images = test_images / 255

# view_images(train_images,train_labels)

def create_model():
    model = keras.Sequential(
        [
            # the input layer - it shall be a flattened array
            # tf.keras.layers.Flatten transforms a 2d array to a 1d array
            keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE),
            # hidden layer 1
            keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"),
            # the output layer
            # 10 nodes, each node contains a score for each of the available classes
            keras.layers.Dense(TOTAL_CLASSES),
        ]
    )
    
    # compile the model
    model.compile(
        optimizer="adam",
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )
    
    return model


def fit(model, train_features, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=100, verbose=2, save=False):
    print("Training...")
    model.fit(train_features, train_labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    if save:
        model.save("digit_classifier")


def score(model, test_features, test_labels, verbose=2):
    # test the model for accuracy
    print("Testing...")
    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_features, test_labels, verbose=verbose)
    print("Test accuracy:", test_acc, ", Test loss: ", test_loss)
    return test_acc, test_loss


def predict(model, features):
    prediction_model = keras.Sequential([model, keras.layers.Softmax()])
    predictions = prediction_model.predict(np.expand_dims(features[0], 0))
    return tf.argmax(predictions[0]), predictions


def load_model(saved=True, features=None, labels=None):
    if saved:
        return keras.models.load_model("digit_classifier")
    
    model = create_model()
    fit(model, features, labels)
    return model


# pygame stuff from here on out

class Colors:
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    GREY = (153, 153, 53)
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)


class Spot:
    def __init__(self, row, col, width):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.x = col * width
        self.y = row * width
        self.color = list(Colors.BLACK)
        self.width = width
    
    def add_color(self):
        for c in range(3):
            self.color[c] += 10 if self.color[c] < 245 else 0
    
    def get_gray_scale(self):
        return sum(self.color) / 3
    
    def get_pos(self):
        return self.row, self.col
    
    def reset(self):
        self.color = list(Colors.BLACK)
    
    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.width))

# create a grid full of Spots
def make_grid(rows, window_width):
    grid = []
    gap = window_width / rows
    for i in range(rows):
        grid.append([])
        for j in range(rows):
            spot = Spot(i, j, gap)
            grid[i].append(spot)
    
    return grid

# draw the grid
def draw_grid(win, rows, window_width):
    gap = window_width // rows
    for i in range(rows):
        pygame.draw.line(win, Colors.GREY, (0, i * gap), (window_width, i * gap))
        for j in range(rows):
            pygame.draw.line(win, Colors.GREY, (j * gap, 0), (j * gap, window_width))

# draw the window
def draw(win, grid, rows, window_width):
    win.fill(Colors.BLACK)
    
    for row in grid:
        for spot in row:
            spot.draw(win)
    
    draw_grid(win, rows, window_width)
    pygame.display.update()

# get the index of the box the user clicked on
def get_indices(pos, rows, window_width):
    gap = window_width // rows
    x, y = pos
    row = y // gap
    col = x // gap
    return row, col

# gets the normalised pixel values from a grid
def get_data(grid):
    image = []
    for r in range(len(grid)):
        image.append([])
        for spot in grid[r]:
            image[r].append(spot.get_gray_scale())

    return [np.array(image, dtype=np.float64) / 255]


# view an image on the gui
def view_image(grid, image):
    for r, row in enumerate(grid):
        for c, spot in enumerate(row):
            spot.color = (image[r][c] * 255,) * 3


def main():
    model = load_model(saved=True, features=train_images, labels=train_labels)
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((TOTAL_PIXELS, TOTAL_PIXELS))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Digit Classifier")
    
    grid = make_grid(IMAGE_DIM, TOTAL_PIXELS)
    # view_image(grid, train_images[2050])
    
    run = True
    while run:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                break
            
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                # clear
                if e.key == pygame.K_c:
                    for row in grid:
                        for spot in row:
                            spot.reset()
                
                # predict
                if e.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    image = get_data(grid)
                    print("Predicted: ",predict(model, image))
        
        # draw
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:  # left mouse
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            row, col = get_indices(pos, 28, 784)
            grid[row][col].add_color()
        
        # erase
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:  # right mouse
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            row, col = get_indices(pos, 28, 784)
            grid[row][col].reset()
        
        draw(win, grid, IMAGE_DIM, TOTAL_PIXELS)


main()
```

I know some of the functions are unnecessary, but just in case you want to reproduce…

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand your query, is it - above two images are not predicted as same?

Comment: yes that’s right

Comment: you can try increasing the dilation (depth/width). https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.15/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html

Comment: Alright @M.Innat, I’ll check that out… But can you elaborate on how that will help solve my problem?